# Underscore js to retrieve data from array

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm assigned a task to get data using underscore js.

This is my JSON :

```
$scope.myData= {
"buslist":
{
    "code":"1",
    "message":"Success",
    "fromStationCode":"71",
    "searchResult": [
        {
            "arrivalTime": "17:00:00",
            "availableSeats": "42",
            "boardingPointDetails": [
                {
                    "code": "1631",
                    "name": "Koyambedu",
                    "time": "09:30:00"
                },
                {
                    "code": "961296",
                    "name": "Nerkundram",
                    "time": "09:45:00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "arrivalTime": "18:00:00",
            "availableSeats": "32",
            "boardingPointDetails": [
                {
                    "code": "2084",
                    "name": "Adyar",
                    "time": "09:30:00"
                },
                {
                    "code": "961296",
                    "name": "Madurai",
                    "time": "09:45:00"
                }
             ]
          }
      ]
   }
 }
```

From this I want only "name" field. By doing this :

```
$scope.bdata = _.pluck($scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult, 'boardingPointDetails');
```

I got all "boardingPointDetails". The result looks like:

```
              [ [
                {
                    "code": "2084",
                    "name": "Adyar",
                    "time": "09:30:00"
                },
                {
                    "code": "961296",
                    "name": "Madurai",
                    "time": "09:45:00"
                }
             ],[
                {
                    "code": "1631",
                    "name": "Koyambedu",
                    "time": "09:30:00"
                },
                {
                    "code": "961296",
                    "name": "Nerkundram",
                    "time": "09:45:00"
                }
            ],[
                 {
                 ... 
                 }
              ]
          ...
           ]
```

Help me to retrieve only "name" from this.

Comment: Will array of names do? Like `['Adyar','Nerkundram']` ?

Comment: yes without using for loop i.e only by means of underscore js and from the result I want to list those data using ng-repeat.

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want array of names like ['Koyambedu', 'Madurai'] then below code would work.

```
$scope.bdata = _.pluck($scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult, 'boardingPointDetails');

// Flatten the data.
$scope.flatbdata = _.flatten($scope.bdata, true);

$scope.flatbdata = $scope.flatbdata.filter(function(d){
                      return d != undefined && d.hasOwnProperty('name')
                   })

// map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results

$scope.names = $scope.flatbdata.map(function(d){
                    return d.name;
                });
```

Refer below links :

http://underscorejs.org/#flatten

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks for reply..Your code works upto flattern.. Then it fails to map..

Comment: Maybe there is some undefined in the flattened data. So, you can filter the data before using map.

$scope.flatbdata = $scope.flatbdata.filter(function(d){
     return d != undefined && d.hasOwnProperty('name')
 });

Comment: ..Thank you so much ...I had been trying this from yesterday..You make my day...It works perfectly..

Comment: As you are using resultant array of names in ng-repeat, so either you can use track by in the ng-repeat in this case duplicate will also appear (and no dups error in angular) or you can just take unique from this array using _.uniq function refer this : http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the array of names, here it is:

```
$scope.bdata = _.pluck($scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult, 'boardingPointDetails');

var res= _.flatten($scope.bdata);
res=_.pluck(res,'name');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Because I'm sure it is working. Gave me this op `[ 'Koyambedu', 'Nerkundram', 'Adyar', 'Madurai' ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = _.pluck(_.flatten($scope.bdata),'name')
```

temp will have `["Koyambedu", "Nerkundram", "Adyar", "Madurai"]`

Comment: what is the output you are looking for? Can you tell the sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$scope = {}; // in real project you don't need this. it's just for snippet.
$scope.myData = {
  "buslist": {
    "code": "1",
    "message": "Success",
    "fromStationCode": "71",
    "searchResult": [{
      "arrivalTime": "17:00:00",
      "availableSeats": "42",
      "boardingPointDetails": [{
        "code": "1631",
        "name": "Koyambedu",
        "time": "09:30:00"
      }, {
        "code": "961296",
        "name": "Nerkundram",
        "time": "09:45:00"
      }]
    }, {
      "arrivalTime": "18:00:00",
      "availableSeats": "32",
      "boardingPointDetails": [{
        "code": "2084",
        "name": "Adyar",
        "time": "09:30:00"
      }, {
        "code": "961296",
        "name": "Madurai",
        "time": "09:45:00"
      }]
    }]
  }
};
$scope.names = _.chain($scope.myData.buslist.searchResult).pluck("boardingPointDetails").flatten(true).map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
}).value();
console.log($scope.names);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.ru/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I'm having my array in $scope. Do you want me save in var??

Comment: It's no matter, where you save your result.